# Get top records for each group

Tags: postgresql, select, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following result from the next query.

```
SELECT   app, srcip,
     Sum(COALESCE(sentbyte, 0)+COALESCE(rcvdbyte, 0)) AS bandwidth 
FROM     $log 
WHERE    logid_to_int(logid) NOT IN (4, 
                                 7, 
                                 14)
GROUP BY app, srcip
HAVING   sum(COALESCE(sentbyte, 0)+COALESCE(rcvdbyte, 0))>0 
ORDER BY bandwidth
```

Result:

```
+----------+----------------+----------+
| app      | srcip          | bandwidth|
+----------+----------------+----------+
| TCP/8080 | 91.236.75.4    | 40       |
| TCP/8080 | 198.74.123.215 | 40       |
| SMTP     | 80.82.64.127   | 44       |
| YouTube  | 192.168.1.170  | 52       |
| TCP/8080 | 121.40.233.129 | 52       |
| HTTP     | 192.168.1.167  | 60       |
| HTTP     | 192.168.1.218  | 60       |
| HTTP     | 199.203.59.117 | 96       |
+----------+----------------+----------+
```

I have been asked to be able to get the following result with the top 15 or top 20 by app.

```
+----------+----------------+----------+
| app      | srcip          | bandwidth|
+----------+----------------+----------+
| TCP/8080 | 121.40.233.129 | 52       |
| TCP/8080 | 91.236.75.4    | 40       |
| TCP/8080 | 198.74.123.215 | 40       |
| SMTP     | 80.82.64.127   | 44       |
| YouTube  | 192.168.1.170  | 52       |
| HTTP     | 199.203.59.117 | 96       |
| HTTP     | 192.168.1.167  | 60       |
| HTTP     | 192.168.1.218  | 60       |
+----------+----------------+----------+
```

I have tried by modifiying the GROUP BY clause but it hasn't worked. Please any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `dataset` is the result of your query. Then the query

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by app order by bandwidth)
from dataset
```

adds a new column `row_number` to `dataset`:

```
   app    |     srcip      | bandwidth | row_number
----------+----------------+-----------+------------
 HTTP     | 192.168.1.218  |        60 |          1
 HTTP     | 192.168.1.167  |        60 |          2
 HTTP     | 199.203.59.117 |        96 |          3
 SMTP     | 80.82.64.127   |        44 |          1
 TCP/8080 | 91.236.75.4    |        40 |          1
 TCP/8080 | 198.74.123.215 |        40 |          2
 TCP/8080 | 121.40.233.129 |        52 |          3
 YouTube  | 192.168.1.170  |        52 |          1
(8 rows)
```

Rows are numbered for each `app`. Now it is easy to limit the number of selected rows in each group:

```
select app, srcip, bandwidth
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by app order by bandwidth)
    from dataset
    ) sub
where row_number < 3

   app    |     srcip      | bandwidth
----------+----------------+-----------
 HTTP     | 192.168.1.218  |        60
 HTTP     | 192.168.1.167  |        60
 SMTP     | 80.82.64.127   |        44
 TCP/8080 | 91.236.75.4    |        40
 TCP/8080 | 198.74.123.215 |        40
 YouTube  | 192.168.1.170  |        52
(6 rows)
```

Read about window functions in [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/tutorial-window.html).